# cloudfoundry worker be same application instance as server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, resque, cloud-foundry

Is it possible for the resque worker and the resque server application to be the same application instance in cloudfoundry. My server application saves a file, the worker instance is a  standalone ruby class that has to read the file from the server instance.

Both are ruby rails applications. I have tried saving it in a postgres bytea but activerecord fails to save with memory error. It could be my meagre dev machine.

I have been told to use Mongodb but my app requires postgres...and box.net is not free. Ideally I need a free way of sharing files or two have them run on the same application instance or three find some other low memory way of having the worker ruby standalone class read the file stored from the rails server upload

Comment: You can have your app(s) use *several* services in CloudFoundry. So it is totally possible for you to use PostgreSQL for whatever reason you need it and Mongo for saving the files. Or you can use an external service (such as S3) as Dan suggests

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Amazon S3 for storing files, it's cheap and I think you pretty much get it for free during the first year! Take a look at the Paperclip gem for integration in to a Rails project.

Comment: I've thought about Paperclip. In particular Paperclip DropBox however 1. Paperclip seems to focus on images, I am saving XML file. 2. I haven't seen Paperclip Dropbox used on an Cloudfoundry services yet. Pretty much free is still too expensive for a hobby project. Finally I don't know if clooudfoundry will let me read from dropbox..Paperclip won't help reading..I only require a temporary storage between my ruby resque server app and my ruby resque worker app

Comment: Looks like reading the following will help. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/files#ruby. No confirmation of it working on cloudfoundry though

Comment: Paperclip doesn't _have_ to be used to store images and it definitely works with CloudFoundry.

Comment: OK. I did not use Paperclip. I found it easier to just use the Dropbox SDK   To pull the file down from Dropbox                                                            session = DropboxSession.new(DROPCONFIG['app_key'], DROPCONFIG['app_secret'])
         session.set_access_token(DROPCONFIG['access_token'], DROPCONFIG['access_token_secret']);
         client = DropboxClient.new(session, 'dropbox')
         puts "after dropbox"
         # in front /
         puts "fileopen"
         out, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata(fname)
         File.open(fpath, 'w+') {|f| f.puts out }